# JavaScript: Search function, remove unordered list elements with search bar input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div.header with a div. search where my input tag exists with my call function.
I also have div.content with all the elements to search for.
They are located in different div tags, but the call function for my JavaScript is only in the input tag.
Problem is when i type in the input tag my console tells me this:

(21) Champions.htm:564 Uncaught TypeError: li.getElementsByClassName is not a function
    at searchfunction (Champions.htm:564)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (Champions.htm:39)

The solution I'm looking for is how I make my input tag remove search elements when I type in a specific champion name. Example:

Typing in A into the input tag should remove all the elements with h3 tags that don't match the search criteria.

Note: My h3 tags are filled in with specific names. And these names are what the searchfunction() should be looking for and removing from the page if they don't match the search criteria.

I'm not much of a JavaScript fan, so most of my tries have been in vain.

```
            function searchfunction() {
                // Definiton af variabler
                // Defining my variables
                var input, filter, div1, div2, ul, li, element, h3, a, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById('s-input');
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById("s-output");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
                element = li.getElementsByClassName('s-element');
                h3 = element.getElementsByTagName('h3');

                // Loop igennem alle elementer og gem dem som ikke matcher søgekriteriet
                // Loop through all elements and hide the ones that doesn't match the criteria
                for (i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
                    a = h3[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        li[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        li[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basement Of Legends</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <link rel="icon"
        href="https://mmls.mmu.edu.my/wordpress/1161100407/wp-content/uploads/sites/33888/2017/01/052b0714815331.562895156726a.png">
    <!-- Font libraries  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Cinzel|Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <main id="website">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="sidebar">
            <a class="linkbox" href="C:\Users\emils\OneDrive\Dokumenter\leaguesite\Frontpage.htm">
                <div title="Go to frontpage" class="sitelinks">
                    <p class="linktext">Frontpage</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a class="linkbox" href="C:\Users\emils\OneDrive\Dokumenter\leaguesite\Champions.htm">
                <div title="Go to champions" class="sitelinks">
                    <p class="linktext">Champions</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a class="linkbox" href="C:\Users\emils\OneDrive\Dokumenter\leaguesite\FAQ.htm">
                <div title="Go to F.A.Q." class="sitelinks">
                    <p class="linktext">F.A.Q.</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Website Head -->
            <div class="header">
                <div class="search">
                    <input title="Search for a specific element" onkeyup="searchfunction()" type="text" id="s-input"
                        placeholder="Search for elements..">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="searchcontent">
                    <ul id="s-output">
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/aatrox-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Aatrox</h3>
                                    <h5>the World Ender</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/ahri-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Ahri</h3>
                                    <h5>the Nine-Tailed Fox</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/champion/square/akali.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Akali</h3>
                                    <h5>the Rogue Assassin</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/alistar-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Alistar</h3>
                                    <h5>the Minotaur</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/amumu-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Amumu</h3>
                                    <h5>the Sad Mummy</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/anivia-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Anivia</h3>
                                    <h5>the Cryophoenix</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/annie-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Annie</h3>
                                    <h5>the Dark Child</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/ashe-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Ashe</h3>
                                    <h5>the Frost Archer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/aurelion-sol-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Aurelion Sol</h3>
                                    <h5>the Star Forger</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/azir-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Azir</h3>
                                    <h5>the Emperor of the Sands</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/bard-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Bard</h3>
                                    <h5>the Wandering Caretaker</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/blitzcrank-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Blitzcrank</h3>
                                    <h5>the Great Steam Golem</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/brand-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Brand</h3>
                                    <h5>the Burning Vengeance</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/braum-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Braum</h3>
                                    <h5>the Heart of the Freljord</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/caitlyn-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Caitlyn</h3>
                                    <h5>the Sheriff of Piltover</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/camille-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Camille</h3>
                                    <h5>the Steel Shadow</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/cassiopeia-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Cassiopeia</h3>
                                    <h5>the Serpent's Embrace</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/chogath-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Cho'gath</h3>
                                    <h5>the Terror of the Void</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/corki-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Corki</h3>
                                    <h5>the Daring Bombardier</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/darius-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Darius</h3>
                                    <h5>the Hand of Noxus</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/diana-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Diana</h3>
                                    <h5>Scorn of the Moon</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/dr-mundo-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Dr. Mundo</h3>
                                    <h5>the Madman of Zaun</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/draven-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Draven</h3>
                                    <h5>the Glorius Executioner</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/ekko-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Ekko</h3>
                                    <h5>the Boy Who Shattered Time</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/elise-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Elise</h3>
                                    <h5>the Spider Queen</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/evelynn-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Evelynn</h3>
                                    <h5>Agony's Embrace</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/ezreal-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Ezreal</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/fiddlesticks-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Fiddlesticks</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/fiora-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Fiora</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/fizz-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Fizz</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/galio-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Galio</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/gangplank-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Gangplank</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/garen-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Garen</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="s-element">
                                <img class="pb" src="https://www.mobafire.com/images/avatars/gnar-classic.png"
                                    alt="champion.png">
                                <div class="Profile">
                                    <h3>Gnar</h3>
                                    <h5>the Prodigal Explorer</h5>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Description: hes O.D.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!-- Content bund -->
                <footer>
                    <ul class="footinfo">
                        <li><a class="foottext" target="_blank" href="">| Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a class="foottext" target="_blank" href="">| Sponsors</a></li>
                        <li><a class="foottext" target="_blank" href="">| e.t.c.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function searchfunction() {
                // Definiton af variabler
                // Defining my variables
                var input, filter, div1, div2, ul, li, element, h3, a, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById('s-input');
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById("s-output");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
                element = li.getElementsByClassName('s-element');
                h3 = element.getElementsByTagName('h3');

                // Loop igennem alle elementer og gem dem som ikke matcher søgekriteriet
                // Loop through all elements and hide the ones that doesn't match the criteria
                for (i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
                    a = h3[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        li[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        li[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> li is an array as getElementsByTagName will return array. You have to either iterate through it or use index in order to use getElementsByClassName - Mohan Ramalingham

Also to make your code alot more readable, select only the neccessary items.

Link to jsfiddle: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/w8arcpvo/)

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#s-output li');
var profile = document.querySelectorAll('.Profile h3');
var searchbar = document.querySelector('.search input');

//Append the eventlistener
searchbar.addEventListener('keyup', searchfunction, false);

function searchfunction(_) {  
  //Value of the searchbar
  var searchbarKeys = _.target.value.toLowerCase(); 

  //Check if the title matches the current value of the searchbar
  items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    //toLowerCase to make it case insensitive (optional)
    var title = profile[index].innerText.toLowerCase()

    if (title.indexOf(searchbarKeys) > -1) {
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me!
I'll remember your comment next time, thanks. :)